# Sort array by group and title

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I have an array of items.

```
var myArray = [
    {group: 'A', title: 'Title 1'},
    {group: 'B', title: 'Title 2'},
    {group: 'C', title: 'Title 3'},
    {group: 'A', title: 'Title 4'},
    {group: 'A', title: 'Title 5'},
    {group: 'B', title: 'Title 6'},
    {group: 'C', title: 'Title 7'}
];
```

I would like to sort array first by group, and inside a group sort by title (alphabetically).

I know that I could create different arrays for every group and then sort them, but I think that this should be done in one .sort function.

Comment: You can do it using a comparator function. It's easy - try something.

Comment: Have you put the logic inside of a [`.sort`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) function? If so, what problems did you run into?

Answer (score 2):

Just sort by both properties, first the group, then the title

```
myArray.sort(function(a,b) {
    var res = a.group.localeCompare(b.group);
    if (res != 0) return res;
    return a.title.localeCompare(b.title);
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/w0j27d5L/)

[localeCompare](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/localeCompare) will sort alphabetically, but note that `Title 16` would come before `Title 2` when doing an alphabetic sort.

Comment: how would you change this function, if positioning of group is predefined. order of group [B, A, C]??

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
myArray.sort(
    function( a, b ) {
        if ( a.group === b.group ) {
            if ( a.title < b.title ) {
                return -1;
            } else if ( a.title > b.title ) {
                return 1;
            } else return 0;
        } else if ( a.group < b.group ) {
            return -1;
        } else return 1;
    }
);
```

Just for reference [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) has plenty of info on the subject.